# Как получить массив или вектор слов из словаря используя поменьше памяти?

Tags: c++

я новичок в с++. Итак есть файл словаря. это текстовый файл размером 136 мб. файл rockyou.txt отсюда: https://github.com/brannondorsey/naive-hashcat/releases/download/data/rockyou.txt

Хочется прочитать это файл в память в виде массива строк или вектора строк для дальнейшей обработки/сортировки.
Что есть на данный момент:

```
std::ifstream infile;
infile.open("D:\\dict\\rockyou.txt", std::ios::binary); // откроем файл как бинарный
infile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
size_t file_size_in_byte = infile.tellg();
std::vector<char> data; // будем использовать для хранения текста
data.resize(file_size_in_byte);
infile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
infile.read(&data[0], file_size_in_byte);
```

**Время выполнения кода 263 мс. Объем памяти занимаемой приложением 148 мб**.
на выходе получаем массив типа char, разделённых '\n' в моём понимании работать с такими данными тяжело.
далее пытаемся перевести этот массив в вектор слов:

```
string tmp;
vector<string> stringList;
int returnPos = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < file_size_in_byte; i++)
{
    if (data[i] == '\n')
    {
        tmp.reserve(i - returnPos);
        memmove(&data[returnPos + 1], &tmp[0], i - returnPos);
        stringList.push_back(tmp);
        returnPos = i;
    }
}
```

спасибо за подсказку Mbo. **Время выполнения при этом получается 73585 мс. и объём памяти 2051 Мб(!!!)**

Далее самый избитый вариант чтения текстового файла в вектор слов:

```
string fileName = "D:\\dict\\rockyou.txt";

std::ifstream input(fileName);

string line;

vector<string> lines;

while (getline(input, line))
{
    lines.push_back(line);        
}
```

**Время выполнения 130481 мс. Объем памяти 2369 мб (!!!)**

Вопрос в том, как получить массив слов из словаря или вектор слов из словаря и при этом остаться в пределах объема занимаемой оперативной памяти не более 2 x РазмерВходногоСловаря Мб.

Comment: ты точно не путаешь виртуальную память с реально занятой? и не потерял лишние пару ноликов во времени чтения — за 2 минуты такой файл можно по дохлому интернету вытянуть...

Comment: Замеры делаются в релизном варианте сборки? Память меряется через профилировщик?

Comment: Для скорости : `lines.push_back(std::move(line));`

Comment: @Fat-Zer нет, ничего не путаю. все данные есть здесь. можете повторить у себя на машине.

Comment: самый избитый вариант чтения это  прямая инициализация вектора:  `vector<string> lines {std::istream_iterator<string>(input),  std::istream_iterator<string>()};`.

Comment: @Deim, нуда... не заметил — у тебя в цикле грязный хак, который вызывает UB... откуда избыточное потребление памяти взялось понятно, хотя временные характеристики всё равно странные: 2ГБ перелопатить не должно быть сложно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer так откуда это избыточное потребление? скрин профилировщика https://ibb.co/RPknLWM

Comment: время выполнения можно уменьшить отключив профилировщик и включив оптимизацию.

Answer (score 1):

Вы как минимум неверно используете ваш `stringList`. Дело в том, что это вообще не `list`, а `vector`. Если вам кажется, что это не существенно, то вы глубоко заблуждаетесь! Дело в том, как используется память в векторе. Предположим у вас в векторе 10 элементов - добавление еще одного элемента повлияет на уже существующие элементы? Ответ зависит от того, есть ли зарезервированная память у вектора, если ее нет - то все содержимое вектора будет релоцировано! При этом будет создан вектор (как правило) размера `prev_size` * 2. Короче из-за неверного использования вектора вы ОЧЕНЬ!!! сильно проседаете по скорости и не эффективно используете память. Чтобы этих проблем не было либо используете настоящий список, либо резервируйте память под вектор (что сложновато, так как нужно будет подсчитать сколько строк в исходном файле).

А вообще, я бы не использовал построковае чтение из файла - эффективнее считать весь файл и разбить данные как вам необходимо.

Comment: Использование листа вместо вектора ускорило выполнение приложения, но не уменьшило объем памяти. первый вариант с переводом char[] -> list<string> время сократилось до 30438 мс. Объем памяти вырос до 3127Мб. Во втором варинте считывания напрямую в лист время уменьшилось до 85140 мс, а объем увеличился до 2883 Мб.

Comment: На счёт прочить весь файл и далее уже работать с ним. в первом варианте я так и сделал. Прочитал его в char[] за 263 мс, а дальнейшая разбивка этого массива всё равно занимает 30000 -73000 мс.

Comment: @Deim думаю вы, как уже писал Fat-Zer, путаете виртуальную память с реально занятой. Предоставте измерения памяти - тогда поговорим

Comment: @Deim что касается разбивки - да, это займет какое-то время, а что вы хотели?

Comment: Скрин приложения  https://ibb.co/SJcs8W1

Comment: @Deim ну а вы уверены в том, что это не виртуальная память? Что это за инструмент?

Comment: Да, уверен на 99%. такой же объем показывает стандартный монитор ресурсов и RamMap

Comment: @Deim что-то мне подсказывает, что эти инструменты не являются профилировщиками памяти

Comment: @Deim к тому же не лишним было бы уточнить: а какой уровень оптимизации вы используете?

Comment: Как я уже писал выше. я новичок в с++, только начинаю его изучать. Поэтому подскажите каким профилировщиком лучше посмотреть объем памяти в моём приложении. На счёт оптимизации /Od

Comment: @Deim воспользуйтесь `massif` - это часть `valgrind`

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, в цикле парсинга строк используется грязный хак:

> ```
> tmp.reserve(i - returnPos);
> memmove(&data[returnPos + 1], &tmp[0], i - returnPos);
> stringList.push_back(tmp);
> returnPos = i;
> ```

Непосредственная запись данных в объект `std::string` с выходом за размер `string::size()` — это UB. Это может вызвать всё что угодно от, как-минимум, инвалидации объекта `std::string` до, как обычно, транснозальной демоноорнитации...

В данном случае, похоже, в `stringList` вставляется строка с произвольным количеством мусора на конце.

Кроме того первая строка здесь получается обрезанной.

В общем корректная реализация должна здесь выглядеть как-то так (подразумевая, что это корректный текстовый файл):

```
for (const char *lstart=data.data(),*lend=strchr(data.data(),'\n');
     lend;
     lstart = lend+1, lend = strchr(lstart,'\n')) {
  stringList.emplace_back(lstart, lend - lstart);
}
```

---

Также `std::string` — довольно тяжёлый объект: каждая строка дополнительно к своему объёму требует *~16 – 40* байт (4 — 5 sizeof(void*)) на служебные цели: указатели/объём/размер/служебные данные аллокатора/менеджера памяти. т.к. строки в данных выше, судя по всему, исключительно короткие, то это составляет значительный объём потребления памяти.

Альтернативы `std::string` здесь:

- Использовать голые указатели, `char *`. Накладные расходы: ~1 слово.
- Написать свой класс-обёртку для облегчённой строки в `char *`. Накладные расходы: ~1—2 слова.
- Использовать `std::string_view` из c++17. Накладные расходы: ~2—3 слова.
- Использовать специализированные структуры для словаря, например, префиксное дерево. Накладные расходы: зависит от реализации и данных.

---

Что не так с временными характеристиками без исправления ошибок и точной методики тестирования сказать невозможно.